# Merging unknown number of rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle

So lets say I have the following sql result:

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| "FALLID" | "PGCH_STATUS" | "PKA_STATUS" | "ZOU_STATUS" |
+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| "687099" | "Grey"        | "Grey"       | "Yellow"     |
| "687099" | "Yellow"      | "Grey"       | "Grey"       |
+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Coming from this statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW UDV_GKH_ABT_STATUS AS
SELECT f.fallid,
CASE
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'ECH' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'ECH' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS ECH_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'EGE' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'EGE' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS EGE_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN (CB_FA LIKE 'EGY' OR CB_FA LIKE 'EGW') AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN (CB_FA LIKE 'EGY' OR CB_FA LIKE 'EGW') AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS EGY_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'EIM' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'EIM' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS EIM_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN (CB_FA LIKE 'EAN' OR CB_FA LIKE 'PAN') AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN (CB_FA LIKE 'EAN' OR CB_FA LIKE 'PAN') AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS GAN_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'PGCH' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'PGCH' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS PGCH_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'PKA' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'PKA' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS PKA_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'PSA' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN CB_FA LIKE 'PSA' AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS PSA_Status,
    CASE
        WHEN (CB_FA LIKE 'POR' OR CB_FA LIKE 'PRO' OR CB_FA LIKE 'PUCH' OR CB_FA LIKE 'ZOU') AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'N' THEN 'Yellow'
        WHEN (CB_FA LIKE 'POR' OR CB_FA LIKE 'PRO' OR CB_FA LIKE 'PUCH' OR CB_FA LIKE 'ZOU') AND C_FA_FREIGABE LIKE 'J' AND C_ABT_ABSCHLUSS LIKE 'J' THEN 'Green'
        ELSE 'Grey'
    END AS ZOU_Status
FROM tblfall f 
LEFT JOIN tblvorgang v on f.fallid = v.fallid and v.vorgangstyp = 'GKH-Formular'
LEFT JOIN qck_abtabrechnung a on v.vorgangsid = a.vorgangsid
LEFT JOIN qck_g2abtabrechnung g on a.layoutdataid = g.layoutdataid
WHERE (sysdate - f.fallstartdatum) <= 1000;
```

But I want the sql result to be only one row, where it takes everything but grey if possible, so like this:

```
+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| "FALLID" | "PGCH_STATUS" | "PKA_STATUS" | "ZOU_STATUS" |
+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| "687099" | "Yellow"      | "Grey"       | "Yellow"     |
+----------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

What way should I use? Do I need another subquery, do I need to modify my query, or is there no way at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: But you took grey in your example.. If there are 10 rows, which values should be taken?

Comment: I'd have given the same answer as Aleksej, only with standard SQL `coalesce(min(case when ech_status <> 'Grey' then ech_status end), 'Grey') as ech_status`, so I don't add this as a separate answer. However, I'd like to point out, that your use of LIKE makes no sense. There are no wildcard patterns to compare, but only simple strings. Use `=` hence. (Why slow down your query by making the DBMS look for patterns when there are none?)

Comment: And you can replace the OR expressions with IN for readability: `when cb_fa in ('POR', 'PRO', 'PUCH', 'ZOU') and c_fa_freigabe = 'J' and c_abt_abschluss = 'N' then 'Yellow'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It will make no difference and internally the optimizer will consider as `=` only.

Comment: @Lalit Kumar: I actually supposed Oracle's optimizer to look through this and replace `LIKE` with `=` internally. But one should not write obfuscated queries, anyway. I another DBMS with a weaker optimizer this might really worsen query's runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your fields are always not null, you can  wrap your view with something like the following:

```
with your_view(FALLID, PGCH_STATUS, PKA_STATUS, ZOU_STATUS) as
(
select '687099', 'Grey', 'Grey', 'Yellow' from dual union all
select '687099', 'Yellow', 'Grey', 'Grey' from dual
)
select FALLID,
       nvl( max( decode (PGCH_STATUS, 'Grey', null, PGCH_STATUS)), 'Grey') as PGCH_STATUS,
       nvl( max( decode (PKA_STATUS , 'Grey', null, PKA_STATUS )), 'Grey') as PKA_STATUS,
       nvl( max( decode (ZOU_STATUS , 'Grey', null, ZOU_STATUS )), 'Grey') as ZOU_STATUS
from your_view
group by FALLID
```

This will return 'Grey' in a column only if all the rows contain 'Grey' in that column; otherwise it will return the maximum string different from 'Grey'.
In your case, it will be:

```
select FALLID,
           nvl( max( decode (PGCH_STATUS, 'Grey', null, PGCH_STATUS)), 'Grey') as PGCH_STATUS,
           nvl( max( decode (PKA_STATUS , 'Grey', null, PKA_STATUS )), 'Grey') as PKA_STATUS,
           nvl( max( decode (ZOU_STATUS , 'Grey', null, ZOU_STATUS )), 'Grey') as ZOU_STATUS
from UDV_GKH_ABT_STATUS 
group by FALLID
```

Comment: I think this is going in the right direction, thank you. But I still have some questions. What exactly is the with-statement? Can I use it inside my view statement or how to I create a view with it? Besides that, your example seems to work only with the exact data I provide. How to make it dynamic?

Comment: The WITH only was used to make an example; I just edited my answer to explain how to use it with your view

Comment: @KaneZ: And your question is not precisely clear: Do you want to change the view or only aggregate the data you get from it? Aleksej has now shown you the latter. If you want to change the view instead, you can use the first query shown (only with your query instead of the mock data).

Comment: Ah okay, your edit made it alot more clear for me what I have to do. @ThorstenKettner Ideally I want to edit my View to make it group by fallid in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sample_data and the WITH clause, put your view in the query.

```
SQL> WITH sample_data(FALLID,PGCH_STATUS,PKA_STATUS,ZOU_STATUS) AS(
  2  SELECT 687099 , 'Grey'  , 'Grey' , 'Yellow'  FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 687099 , 'Yellow', 'Grey' , 'Grey'    FROM dual
  4  )
  5  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
  6  SELECT MAX(fallid),
  7    NVL(MAX(
  8    CASE
  9      WHEN PGCH_STATUS = 'Grey'
 10      THEN ''
 11      ELSE PGCH_STATUS
 12    END), 'Grey') PGCH_STATUS,
 13    NVL(MAX(
 14    CASE
 15      WHEN PKA_STATUS = 'Grey'
 16      THEN ''
 17      ELSE PKA_STATUS
 18    END), 'Grey') PKA_STATUS,
 19    NVL(MAX(
 20    CASE
 21      WHEN ZOU_STATUS = 'Grey'
 22      THEN ''
 23      ELSE ZOU_STATUS
 24    END), 'Grey') ZOU_STATUS
 25  FROM sample_data
 26  GROUP BY fallid;

MAX(FALLID) PGCH_STATUS PKA_STATUS  ZOU_STATUS
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
     687099 Yellow      Grey        Yellow

SQL>
```

On a side note, your usage of `LIKE` makes no sense:

```
LIKE 'ECH'
```

Optimizer will evaluate it as:

```
= 'ECH'
```

Although, it makes no difference to the performance as the optimizer is smart enough to evaluate as `=`.

You can check the explain plan,

```
SQL> explain plan for select * from dual where dummy like 'X';

Explained.

SQL> select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("DUMMY"='X')

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: This is actually just Aleksej's answer plus the comments already given.